# How to use imported libraries with symfony's asset mapper ? (sf 7.0.4)

Tags: symfony, symfony-assetmapper

I wanted to try symfony's brand new assetmapper on my latest project, without external imports, it works just fine, but I cant yet get how to make it work when it comes to imported libraries...

I used symfony doc command `bin/console importmap:require ...` to import the libraries

[image]

If I alias the imports it seems they cannot be found...

[image]

And if I dont alias the imports, the link is not broken anymore but no way to use the libraries...

[image]

Thank you for your future help!